# Does the XML-RPC in OpenERP keep the database connections after each transaction?

Tags: odoo

We are using OpenERP v6. I wonder if OpenERP's XML-RPC keeps the database connections after each transaction? Or how do I check in our system if there's proper session handling for the XMLRC methods?

Reason for asking: We are experiencing lag/seriously slow OpenERP environment in both out test environment (used for UAT) and production

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

XML-RPC in OpenERP is connection less.
OpenERP create some connections to DB and keep it in connection pool. Every time OpenERP need some data from DB, it uses one of the DB connection from connection pool. There is no session is handled for xml-rpc. Every successful xml-RPC call will commit the transactions to the DB